# How to replace the value of 3rd column based on the value of 4th column

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file `test.txt` as below:

```
000092;;;;2004;;;;N;;;;N

000098;;;;0086;;;;Y;;;;Y
```

I want to update the value of 4th columns based on the value of 3rd column. If the value of 4th column is `N` replace the 3rd column value with `NA` and if the value of 4th column is `Y` then replace the 3rd column with `UPDATE`.

Output should be as below:

```
000092;;;;2004;;;;NA;;;;N

000098;;;;0086;;;;UPDATE;;;;Y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F ';;;;' -v 'OFS=;;;;' '$4 == "Y" { $3 = "UPDATE" } $4 == "N" { $3 = "NA" } { print; }' test.txt
```

with `test.txt` as specified in the question prints

```
000092;;;;2004;;;;NA;;;;N
000098;;;;0086;;;;UPDATE;;;;Y
```

As stated in the question I assume you really have only 4 columns separated by `;;;;` (4 semicolons), not 13 columns separated by `;` (single semicolon). So this script will not work if you have lines with additional data between the groups of 4 `;`.

Explanation:

`-F ';;;;'` set input field separator
`-v 'OFS=;;;;'` set output field separator
`$4 == "Y"` condition: if field 4 is `Y`
`{ $3 = "UPDATE" }` action: modify field 3
the same for `N` and `NA`
`{ print; }` unconditional action: print (resulting) line

Answer (score 1):

With awk, first set the input n output field separators, then look for that record in the input data that has a y or an n only, then do the changes, and finally print to stdout.

```
$ awk -F';;;;' '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS}
    $4 ~ /^[NY]$/{$3 = ($4 == "N") ? "NA" : "UPDATE"}1
' file
```

Another approach can be:

```
$ awk -F';;;;' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS;a["N"]="NA";a["Y"]="UPDATE"}
  $4 ~ /^[NY]$/{$3 = a[$4]}1' file
```